# How to measure the time when using Sockets and concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, time, concurrency

I am emulating a simple connection between a client and a server. The client petitions are sent and the server proccesses them in a concurrent way: the server class extends Thread and the task is run when the object is created.

The server is always open, listening to petitions, when there is one then a object is created using the socket as a parameter, and the task is then run as I said.

I am trying to measure the time it takes to process all the petitions one client sends at once, but I can't manage to do it. With threads, pools and such I would usually take the initial time and take the time when I know everything finished and voila (usually after a join or checking if the pool is terminated).

But now I can't manage to know when all the tasks are done, because the server is always running.

Any ideas?

I'm going to try to sum up the code in case someone didn't understand:

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class MyServer extends Thread
    {
       Socket socket;

       public MyServer(Socket s) { socket=s; this.start(); }

       public void run() 
       { 
          // proccessing of the data sent by the client (just printing values)
          // data is read properly, don't worry
          socket.close(); 
       }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          int port = 2001; // the same one the client is using
          try
          {
             ServerSocket chuff = new ServerSocket(port, 3000);
             while (true)
             {
                Socket connection = chuff.accept();
                new MyServer(connection);
             }
          } catch (Exception e) {}
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether a client will (a) send more work down a single connection later, or (b) open multiple connections at once.

If it won't ever do either, then the processing of one connection is the unit of work to time (and in fact I think all you need to time is how long the thread is alive for).

If a client might do one of those things, then if you can, change your protocol so that clients send work in one single packet; then measure how long it takes to process one of those packets. This gives you an unambiguous definition of what you are actually measuring, the lack of which might be what is causing you problems here.

Comment: It's just a test, nothing too complicated, I'm learning, so it's neither. But if the client is constantly running how do I time the petitions? Let's say 20 petitions are sent, so new `MyServer(connection)` is called 20 times. How do I measure the time between the first call and the moment the last task running is completed (and how do I know when this happens?)?

Comment: See my 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

For each incoming connection, I would do it as follows:

1. Handover the connection to a Runnable class that performs the work.
2. Measure the time taken by the run method and at the end of run method, prepare a Statistics object that contains the client details and the time taken to run and post it to a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.
3. Have another thread that would poll this queue, extracts the Statistics object and updates the database or data where per-client run times are tracked.

Comment: Let's say a client sends n petitions at once. What I want to know is just the time lapse between the moment the first petition is started to get processed and the moment all the petitions are processed.

Comment: So, you are interested in points in time when the processing started and when all are processed. For that, one should know the number of petitions from a given client to keep track of the count of petitions processed and report back when the count reaches the total.

Comment: I know the total number of petitions, it's public.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when no more connections are incomming you must set a SO_TIMEOUT, otherwise `accept()` blocks forever. Timeouts are enabled by invoking [ServerSocket.setSoTimeout(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29).

To measure performance each thread could update a shared variable with the time when they completed the task. Mark this variable as `volatile` to keep the values synchronized and wait until all your threads have terminated and `accept` has raised a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`.

Note that you're also measuring the network latency between the incoming requests, is this inteded?

Comment: Where should I call the setSoTimeout method? And where would I set the initial time, when do I know the first task is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommended instead of creating new Thread every time on accepting the client task consider using ExecutorService instead.

If you want to check the timing for performing number of tasks by server may be you can send list of task in one go as mentioned above and use CompletionService to check total time to complete all tasks(Runnable). Below is a sample test class to show how to capture completion time:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ServerPerformanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Total time taken : " + totalTimeTaken(1000, 16));
    }

    public static long totalTimeTaken(final int taskCount, final int threadCount) {
        //Mocking Dummy task send by client
        Runnable clientTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("task done");
            }
        };

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Prepare list of tasks for performance test
        List<Runnable> tasks = Collections.nCopies(taskCount, clientTask);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executorService);

        //Submit all tasks 
        for (Runnable _task : tasks) {
            completionService.submit(_task, "Done");
        }

        //Get from all Future tasks till all tasks completed
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            try {
                completionService.take().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //do something
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //do something
            }
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (endTime - startTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using executors is my seconds version, but I want to work with both of them. Thanks for the code, I will use some time on it to see if it clarifies my issue.